# Typescript and useRef hook causing type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I made a custom Checkbox component to handle events differently, code below:

```
const DoubleClickCheckbox = ({ filter, handleDoubleClick, handleSingleClick }: DCCheckboxProps) => {
  const delay = 400;
  const timer = useRef(null);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const flags = useFlags();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      timer.current && clearTimeout(timer.current);
    };
  }, []);

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  const onClick = (e) => {
    if (flags.csRequireFilters) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      handleSingleClick(filter);
      return;
    }

    switch (e.detail) {
      case 1:
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
          handleSingleClick(filter);
        }, delay);
        break;
      case 2:
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        clearTimeout(timer.current);
        handleDoubleClick(filter);
        break;
      default:
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        clearTimeout(timer.current);
        return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.filter} onClick={onClick} onKeyDown={() => {}} role="button" tabIndex={0}>
      <Checkbox
        label={filter.label}
        className={classes.checkbox_custom}
        checked={filter.selected}
        checkedIcon={filter.mandatory ? <Icons.CheckboxDoubleClick /> : <Icons.CheckboxSingleClick />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would like to dump my `eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment` and `ts-ignore`.

If I rewrite my code it reads as below, I get a typescript error:

```
  case 1:
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      handleSingleClick(filter);
    }, delay);
    break;
```

The error is: `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'null'.` I have tried various other tricks, for example: `const timer = useRef<React.MutableRefObject<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>>(null);`.

It did not help either.

Please advise

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with this timer ref? i'm not following. can you explain what the use case you're trying to implement? seems like ref might not necessarily be the solution.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a number that represents an id of that timer. You can use either `number` type or `NodeJS.Timeout` alongside with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you'r ref can be `null` or be a `number` (`ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>` is `number`):

```
const timer = React.useRef<number | null>(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `useRef(null)` implicitly sets it's type as `null`. You should define it as `const timer = useRef<null | () => void>(null)`